# Margin-Top < 0 leads to wrong zooming

Tags: html, css, overflow, zooming, margin

I want a child element to be zoomable and centered. If you change the zoom of the child to 200% you can see that the element's top is violet, but you can't zoom up. How can I fix this? I think it's because the margin-top is below zero.

***Zoom 100% :***

```css
#child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, violet, yellow, green, pink);
  width:50px;
  height:400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    zoom: 100%;
}

#parent {
  background-color:blue;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale();
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

***Zoom 200% :***

```css
#child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, violet, yellow, green, pink);
  width:50px;
  height:400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    zoom: 200%;
}

#parent {
  background-color:blue;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale();
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding `'display: flex; align-items: center;'` to the parent and removing the position absolute (incl. positions)

```css
#child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, violet, yellow, green, pink);
  width: 50px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  zoom: 200%;
}

#parent {
  background-color:blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the height of `#child` is in pixels, the zoom function will zoom in on the number of pixels. If you use `height: ..%` the height percentage will scale on your `zoom`.

Comment: Then the height stays at ..% it isn't zooming in.